# how to include odt in org mode

Tags: org-mode, libreoffice, odt

I am trying to write in org mode and then export to an odt file. But some tables are better edited in libreoffice, can I include an external odt file that contains the table in org mode? Is there any org keyword for libreoffice's master document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do that.  Create through libreoffice (or whatever you want, I tried with abiword) a `table.odt` file containing the table.  Then copy the xml table code (the `<table:table>` element) from the `content.xml` file inside `table.odt` (which actually is a zip file) into file `table.org`, inside `#+BEGIN/END_ODT`.

I tried this and created the following `table.org` file:

```
#+BEGIN_ODT
   <table:table table:name="Table1">
    <table:table-column/>
    <table:table-column/>
    <table:table-row>
     <table:table-cell table:style-name="Table1_col1_row1">
      <text:p text:style-name="P1" >1</text:p>
     </table:table-cell>
     <table:table-cell table:style-name="Table1_col2_row1">
      <text:p text:style-name="P2" >2</text:p>
     </table:table-cell>
    </table:table-row>
    <table:table-row>
     <table:table-cell table:style-name="Table1_col1_row2">
      <text:p text:style-name="Normal" >3</text:p>
     </table:table-cell>
     <table:table-cell table:style-name="Table1_col2_row2">
      <text:p text:style-name="P1" >4</text:p>
     </table:table-cell>
    </table:table-row>
   </table:table>
#+END_ODT
```

Finally, #+include `table.org` in your main org file.

```
#+INCLUDE: "~/table.org"
```

Exporting the main org file to odt does include the table as expected (in this simple example at least).  Of course you need to recreate the `table.org` file each time you edit the table.  But I'm confident you could automate this with some shell (or whatever, certainly including emacs!) scripting:

- extract content.xml from odt,
- get  element from content.xml (eg with `sed`),
- dump this to `table.org`, enclosed in `#+BEGIN/END_ODT`

Comment: Perfect. So now create a odt file for each table or multi-column section, and use a script to remove all unecessary part not related to the content of intereste. Or maybe the script to remove is simpler than the script to extract?

Comment: @godblessfq Extracting seems easier to me, something like `sed -n '/<table:table/,/<\/table:table>/p' content.xml` (Assuming only one table in content.xml, of course).